# Get all inactive values from a picklist to change api names successfully

Tags: picklist, in-active-picklist-values

We are trying to change the API names for picklist values in the "Industry" standard field on the "Account" object.

Unfortunately, we are encountering an error message that says "Error: Duplicate API Name" whenever we attempt to make the desired changes.

Although there are no duplicates in the active section, we suspect that the issue lies with the InActive section.

The challenge is that there are thousands of values in the inActive values, and navigating through each page using the "Next Page" option is not ideal.

Is there a way to obtain a list of the InActive API values so that we can change them to something else or delete them, without having to go through each of the thousands of values?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

try this
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account.Industry.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> P = F.getPicklistValues();
if(p.isActive())
{
}
else
{
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @Yamini,
I tried to do so already, but the "else" is never called, cause it gets only the Acitve values.